# Command /bin/bash not overriding default entrypoint

Tags: docker

I am trying to override a custom image's entrypoint so that I invoke binarys.

However the following command fails:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint "/bin/bash -c" my-image:latest cat /etc/os-release
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/bash -c": stat /bin/bash -c: no such file or directory: unknown.
```

How should it be formulated so that `/bin/bash -c` becomes my entrypoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `sh -c` wrapper just to run a simple command.  However, overriding `ENTRYPOINT` can be a little bit awkward.  The generic formulation is

```sh
docker run --rm \
  --entrypoint COMMAND \
  IMAGE-NAME:TAG \
  ARGUMENTS
```

So, in your example,

```sh
docker run --rm --entrypoint cat my-image:latest /etc/os-release
```

If you insist on using `bash -c`, it's the same construction

```
docker run --rm --entrypoint bash my-image:latest -c 'cat /etc/os-release'
```

This is kind of an awkward construction.  If you control the Dockerfile, consider changing `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD`; or if you have an `ENTRYPOINT` script that does some first-time setup then launches the main container process, split out that command into a separate `CMD` and make the last line of the script be `exec "$@"`.  Then you can run a much more natural

```sh
# If the image's CMD is honored and is an ordinary shell command
docker run --rm my-image:latest cat /etc/os-release
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the entrypoint altogether with `--entrypoint ""`:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint "" my-image:latest cat /etc/os-release
```

You try to set the entrypoint to the program `"/bin/bash -c"` with a space and -c which does not exist.